# ListView does not autosize column

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, c++-cli, clr

I'm trying to build a Windows C++/CLR ListView with 4 columns. Three of them are fixed width, but the first one I need auto-sized. Here is the code:

```
int offset = 250;
int ypos = 35;
int size = 560;
int height = 185;

myListView = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView();

myListView->Name = "MyListView";
myListView->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Segoe UI", 10, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
    static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
myListView->Location = System::Drawing::Point(offset, ypos - 25);
myListView->Size = System::Drawing::Size(size, height);
myListView->GridLines = true;
myListView->Sorting = System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder::Ascending;
myListView->View = System::Windows::Forms::View::Details;
myListView->HeaderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ColumnHeaderStyle::Clickable;
myListView->Scrollable = true;
myListView->FullRowSelect = true;
myListView->MultiSelect = false;

myListView->Columns->Add("Name", -2, System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Left);
myListView->Columns->Add("Dir 1", 130, System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Left);
myListView->Columns->Add("Dir 2", 130, System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Left);
myListView->Columns->Add("Saved Date/Time", 130, System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Left);
```

I´m using `-2` for the `Name` column:

```
myListView->Columns->Add("Name", -2, System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Left);
```

My larger element is at the fifth column, as:

```
John
Mary
Peter
Paul
This is a autosize test
```

The fifth line gets chopped and does not resize the whole column as I expected to see, and I don´t know what may be causing this.

Comment: -2 is not documented to be a valid choice for the column width.  But does have an affect, just not one you like.  It will autosize to the column heading string, not the column content.  Pretty visible when you do this in the designer, note how it instantly replaces -2.

Comment: @Ðаn - of course there is, that's why programmers in the [c++-cli] tag like to use it.  And your frequent commentary about it is never useful to them.  Project > Add New Item > UI > Windows Form and CLR User Control item templates.

Comment: Dan, your comment may be valid, but is not related at all to the question. I have an old code done in C++/CLI that instantiate programatically visual elements. I have to support it and I don´t see nothing wrong about it. I don´t thing I need to explain these things before asking about C++/CLI usage and these comments does not add too much to what I need, that is, to autoresize the column.

Comment: @Hans, I´m not using the designer - all programatically. What them is the option to autoresize using the column content ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.autoresize(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1